# Does this old attic door contain asbestos?

Tags: asbestos

There was an old disused attic door in the attic of my house which I was going to disassemble and dispose of, as it was taking up a lot of space (and rather too large to move and dispose of in one piece by myself). I figured the contractor that a previous owner used was in the same situation and just threw the door behind the chimney and called it a day.

However, after partially disassembling it, I was going to peel off the water damaged cardboard, but it appears the door is filled with a white, maybe asbestos, insulation.
[image: white insulation protruding through cardboard]
The hardware on the door uses all nails, flathead screws and staples, so it's possible the door predates 1932 (the invention of phillips head screws).

Is this obviously or obviously not asbestos insulation? I'm not sure what the best course of action here is, the rest of the insulation in the house is fiberglass or cellulose, but this door likely predates all of that.

Edit: Test came back, 100% mineral wool, no asbestos.

Comment: It's only obvious to a test lab. Don't get overcharged, shop around. Send in a sample. Unless it's something actually marked with a brand name that indicates asbestos (like Transite board) you cannot tell by looking at it, or looking at a picture of it.

Comment: Yeah, get it tested.

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards, helps to get confirmation though. Thanks! If it is asbestos, do companies charge a ton for abatement if it is a single object? (e.g. one door)

Comment: "We [the EPA] strongly encourage you to engage a licensed or certified asbestos abatement contractor to do any work involving asbestos." - read, *you* can do w/e *you* want in *your* own home. Commercial property; you have to hire someone. - Wear a mask, **fold it up** or break it, put it in contractor bags, depose of 'properly'. If that means you have to take it somewhere, then skip all that and just take it somewhere. You being exposed to it one time is not a concern. Be a pipe fitter for 50y starting in 1930 and you'll die like my grand father did. Otherwise, w/e.

Comment: That would go in my garbage can because it looks like fiberglass anyway. But here you go: [National List of Asbestos Landfills](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj685Wqy-L6AhWNpIkEHQWEDHAQFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnepis.epa.gov%2FExe%2FZyPURL.cgi%3FDockey%3D000001EP.TXT&usg=AOvVaw0ek35jb27dMr3iKXIcLlWo) - Double bagged, tapped, and labeled *asbestos*.

Comment: *not* obviously asbestos. Doesn't look like "Zonolite, Kaylo and Limpet" and if [their first picture](https://www.asbestos.com/products/insulation/) isn't both of the two most common (pink and yellow) types of fiberglass insulation, well then I'll be....

Comment: [Does this look like asbestos?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/72439/does-this-look-like-asbestos) - wrong question. *How do I dispose of this door (in my own house, or in a building with less than four units)?*